# Does 3-valued logic ever provide practical benefits over 2-valued logic?

Tags: sql, null

I was looking at an SQL query recently and found what I think is likely a bug.  It was related to case statements on inequalities.  I was trying to replace it with a min/max type alternate and when testing, I was getting different results.  Here's a simplfied example of the SQL that I was trying to simplify:

`CASE A > B THEN A ELSE B`

The upshot was that in the case statement, if either value in the inequality was `null`, the else statement was the result.  That is: 1 > `null` is equivalent in a CASE statement to `false` and null > 1 is also equivalent to `false`.  So regardless of which one is null (or both,) the `ELSE` clause ends up as the result.

My initial assumption was that this could be replaced with a function such as a `greatest` or `least` (Oracle) but that's where I went wrong.  If any argument to those functions is `null`, the result is `null`.  That's opposed to the situation with the case statement where only in the case that `B` is `null`, will the result be `null` (i.e.: if `A` is null, the result will be whatever `B` is.)

OK.  I figured out my major malfunction and probably identified a defect.  Here's the question:  Is there any practical value to this complexity?  I can't think of any time that this kind of 3-valued logic has been useful, but I can think of innumerable times that it has been a cause of bugs.  I know there is a theory underlying it.  Is it simply non-pragmatic or is there something more to this idea that I am missing?

To clarify my 'complaint', throughout my education and *most*, of my coding career, I can expect certain things to be hold (using SQL syntax) such as:

- if `A <> B` is `false`, then `A = B` is `true`.
- if `A <> C` is `false` and `B <> C` is `false` then `A <> B` is `false`.
- if `A > B` is `false`, then `A <= B` is `true`.
- if `A` is `null`, and `B` is `null`, `A = B` is `true`. Or simply: `A = A` and `NOT A = NOT A`

None of these hold in SQL if nulls are involved.

The alternative to this isn't some novel solution. I would just prefer more standard boolean semantics.  And my question is are there any fundamental reasons that SQL **needs** to violate those assumptions when nulls are involved.  Would it make SQL harder to use in some way that I am not seeing?  As for what should the result of 'A > B' be if one of them is 'null'?  That's a good question. I suppose an error would be fine, or if there's some non-error result, it should work such that if `A > B` is `false`, and `A != B`, `B > A` is `true`.

I realized as I was looking through the answers and comments that part of my annoyance is the behavior of `greatest` and `least` in Oracle.  If any of the values passed to these is `null`, the result is `null`.  This means that `greatest(1, 2, null) -> null` and `least(1, 2, null) -> null`.  Naively this implies that all the values are the same.  But that's not what it means.  It behaves like a silent exception.  I realize that this is not a direct result of SQL 3-valued logic but it seems related to me.  I would expect it to work like `min` or `max` works across a number of rows.  In any event, the larger question still holds around how nulls are treated in SQL.

To make this more concrete, this is the structure of clause I was attempting to simplify:

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE(apple, pear) >  
  (CASE WHEN kumquat > orange THEN kumquat ELSE orange END)
  THEN COALESCE(apple, pear)
  ELSE (CASE WHEN kumquat > orange THEN kumquat ELSE orange END)
```

It's clear (for reasons that are outside the scope of this question) that the intention is to get the greatest value of the coalesced apple/pear, kumquat, and orange values.  So I rewrote it as:

```
GREATEST(COALESCE(apple, pear), kumquat, orange)
```

Which I consider much clearer.  However, when I tested the change, I was getting different results for the reasons already discussed.  Note that while my replacement was flawed, the original has a subtle defect.  That is if `kumquat` is `null`, we get whatever the value of `orange`.  If `orange` is `null`, we get `null`.

I came up with this which is closer to the original intent and probably works based on some assumptions about the data:

```
GREATEST(COALESCE(apple, pear), COALESCE(kumquat, orange), COALESCE(orange, kumquat))
```

But I find this unsatisfyingly obfuscated.  Side note: suggestions for a cleaner solution to this specific issue are welcome.  Unfortunately, I cannot change the schema or the way the data is created.

P.S. In one of the comments @Falco made a good point about this coming from a different angle.  In a nutshell, this is the behavior of `CASE A > B THEN  A ELSE B` in SQL CASE statements (A on x-axis, B on y-axis):

```
   | 1 | 2 | ?
   --------------
1  | 2 | 2 | 1
2  | 2 | 2 | 2
?  | ? | ? | ?
```

Wouldn't this make more sense?

```
   | 1 | 2 | ?
   --------------
1  | 2 | 2 | ?
2  | 2 | 2 | ?
?  | ? | ? | ?
```

Sorry to keep updating this but I the answers and comments are helping me get to the underlying problem I have with this.  Basically, while SQL supports 3-valued logic, there are many places where things are collapsed into binary conditions.  And the way that happens is awkward and confusing.  For example, a JOIN condition either succeeds or fails.  There's no (to my knowledge) unknown result of a join condition.

```
condition | result
-------------------
true      | success
false     | fail
unknown   | fail
```

It's this 'impedance' mismatch or asymmetry that I think creates issues.  And while the answers have been thought-providing, none so far have shown any example argument or example of how 3-valued logic makes things easier or otherwise better.  The only thing so far has been this [wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)) which states that this is way to address the [semipredicate problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semipredicate_problem) or in simplistic terms, nulls are an alternative to raising exceptions.

An acceptable answer will provide a specific concrete example of when 3 value logic simplifies or improves a solution over common 2-valued logic solutions.  Informally, when is 3-valued logic something other than a [footgun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/footgun).  Any example where 3-valued logic saved you or someone you know from a problem instead of creating one will suffice.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A minor frame challenge: your question does not seem to be "when is three-valued logic useful?" but rather "when is the specific flavor of three-valued logic that SQL uses useful?"

To illustrate the distinction, consider the "optional/maybe" suggestion in another answer: it is also a three-valued logic, but with different semantics. To wit, in most programming languages that have the concept, attempting to use a non-existent value in a logical proposition results in an immediate termination of the entire expression as an error, rather than propagating it.

As to when this specific set of semantics are useful? Occasions do arise, but often someone familiar with the semantics used by other languages are using a mental model that will not lead them to think in those terms. This isn't necessarily a good thing or a bad thing per se, although in general thinking in a model that does not align with the language actually being used leads (as you note) to a high chance for bugs.

I would argue that SQL's NULL value is best described in English as neither "a lack of a value" nor as quite "we don't know", although the latter is closer. Rather, I would characterize it as "undecidable" or, alternatively, what is sometimes referred to as "Mu" — meaning "your question has an invalid assumption".

- The question in an outer join is "for each element in A, what elements in B match up to it?" with the presumption that there are in fact any that do — so when none do, that is the answer.
- For most logical and comparative operators, there is no meaningful answer when at least one of the operands is unavailable. "Is 1 greater than some value that is not available?" is impossible to answer… but so is "is a value that is unavailable equal to another value that is unavailable?"

The largest "gotcha" involved is that "if/then/else" is still treated as a "true binary" construct, in that unlike an outer join, there is no implicit assumption that the control operand has a value (if there were, then the correct answer would be NULL because the entire proposition would be undecidable). Note that this isn't an inconsistent definition or semantic, it is just the most obvious case where this happens, and the fact that it happens in one of the most used logical constructs is arguably a poor design decision.

To answer the literal question: yes, such cases exist. As given in another answer, an example would be "if age >= 18" being used to control availability of some content. If you actually mean "are there cases that cannot be replicated using the logic I am more familiar with" (where a missing value that isn't accounted for simply blows up), then no — either set of semantics can fairly easily (if somewhat verbosely) be made to behave like the other. It is, however, more concise for asking some sorts of questions in the domain that SQL is related to (set calculus).

Addendum to address comments:

I think both the part asking for a specific example and the comment about "if age >= 18" actually tie together, in that is one example where you can deliberately make use of the fact that it will fail both when age is < 18 and when age is unknown. That doesn't invalidate "I would prefer Option" — as originally noted, the two sets of semantics can be converted using exactly that sort of tool. Keep in mind that the expression is not in fact "downmixed" to false — it evaluates to NULL, and because the "if" conditional is treated as a strict statement, both NULL and false fail it.

It may be helpful to keep in mind that SQL, as a language, is fundamentally structured around manipulating and querying data *sets* — as such, some of the semantics of its operations are actually derived from set theory based boolean algebra, rather than arithmetic boolean algebra (the type most programmers are used to). They are derived just as consistently, but from a different starting point, in this case one that is more "natural" to the domain which the language was actually written to deal with.

As a somewhat skewed analogy, consider verb handling in German and English. In German, "like Yoda speak you; your verbs at the end of the clauses you put." [Edit: only for some clause types, apparently! Thanks for the correction.] Rendered in English, this is still entirely comprehensible, but it is going to sound "odd" and there are some cases where such an "unfiltered" translation of a German sentence would introduce ambiguity in the English form that would not be present in the original. Neither one is "more correct", but if you try to speak in one while thinking in the other, you're very likely to get results that may be workable but also don't necessarily do quite what was intended.

At the end of the day, the not-necessarily-entirely-satisfying answer is "SQL was not written for folks who develop primarily linear code". It is its own beast, in the same way (and more or less at the same level) as procedural, functional, and object-oriented code are their own beasts. This is one fairly major reason for the popularity of using tools like ORM frameworks to adapt between OO code and SQL — it helps avoid the inevitable complexities that folks lose track of when they don't use a language as a primary tool on a regular basis. They do have a cost, but that cost is often more than worth paying if your primary audience are developers who don't sling SQL for a living.

Edit 2:

One thing I just caught, re-reading the original question, was the statement "if A<>B is false, then A=B is true". This highlights exactly the point that things go off the rails: what you are expecting to be true… actually is. Because when A and/or B is null, "A<>B" and "A=B" both evaluate to NULL, not true or false. Only when that is "collapsed" by a forced binary decision (for example, use in a 'where' clause, where there is no 'third option' when deciding whether a row is included) does it get treated as "effectively false".

Comment: You are hitting the mark here. Specifically "As to when this specific set of semantics are useful? Occasions do arise, but often someone familiar with the semantics used by other languages are using a mental model that will not lead them to think in those terms." This is concise way of stating my quandary.  Am I failing to use these constructs correctly because of my mental model?  What are some examples of the 'occasions that arise'?

Comment: I do want to challenge your challenge.  The fact is that Option approach is still a 2-valued logic solution.  Your truth table for (e.g.) AND has 4 scenarios, not 9.  The Option option is (IMO) more evidence that we don't need 3-valued logic at all.  Exceptions on the other hand ...

Comment: Why did someone downvote the best (most relevant) answer so far?

Comment: W/ regard to the 'age > 18' condition.  I would very much prefer to have an error raised.  This is exactly where I see problems: in a simple conditional (e.g.: join), 'unknown' will be indistinguishable from 'false'.  But really the answer is you asked a question that is unanswerable. 'Downmixing' that to 'false' is a problem IMO, not a solution.  What this means in practical terms is that the person asking the question is forced to preemptively address that possibility either through constraints (not always possible) or extra logic.  I'm still not seeing how this helps.

Comment: I still consider this to be the best answer yet.  Please consider addressing my comments.  Let say comparing a value threw an error much like division by zero typically does in SQL engines.  'Coalesce' has been noted in other answers and it would seem to solve that issue with a exception regime as well.  Why is it better to silently 'fail' (IMO) versus explicitly failing?  In my experience these silent errors not only create odd corner-cases but also make complex SQL extremely difficult to understand, maintain, and refactor.

Comment: On your last paragraph, I think that the reason for ORM being the ["Vietnam of Computer Science"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science/) may be largely due to the mismatch between trinary and binary logic.

Comment: Reading through that article, the following snippet caught my eye:

… bring relational concepts (which, at heart, are set-based) into mainstream programming languages, making it easier to bridge the gap between "sets" and "objects"

This is precisely the crux of the problem. It isn't _just_ trinary logic, but rather, that relational logic as traditionally represented by SQL requires the developer to "shift gears" from whatever language they use on a day-to-day basis. The trinary logic aspects are a symptom of that larger issue.

Comment: In my (personal, practical, but by no means universal) experience some flavor of "manual mapping" and "acceptance of ORM limitations" (mostly in the form of "make the simple stuff simple, and pay a couple of devs to be able to handle the complicated stuff") seems to be the net result, although "manage all relationships on the language side and use the DB as pure dumb storage" certainly has its merits and folks seem to not infrequently end up there, just not always by design… on the other hand, that has some very real costs, as well.

Comment: Not 100% on this but it seems to me that a relational DB in 3NF (I'm not great with my normal forms, so I could be picking the wrong one) maps to objects quite well.  I'm much more comfortable with OO and sets (well, maps usually) are one of my go-to solutions.  I'm not sure I agree with most (or much) of that article aside from: it's hard, I just wanted to add a reference to a (perhaps) emotionally charged analogy.

Comment: "manage all relationships on the language side and use the DB as pure dumb storage": I think that if you are there, a non-relational or 'NoSQL' DB is probably the way to go.  SQL works great (to a point.)  Success is rarely purely a result of chance.  Where I see things go wrong is when people go deep with SQL.  I specifically use the word 'deep' here because that's where these null semantics start creating havoc, IMO.

Comment: Entirely fair, and I think your assessment about 3NF is probably not far off (I can't say with authority whether it is quite on target, I haven't faffed about with the proper normal form definitions in far too long). I think the best answer for 98% of developers is an ORM that doesn't actually _let_ you write SQL directly without using a "no, really, let me keep both pieces if it breaks" side path. If "ORM.If(Person::Age, GreaterThanOrEqualTo, 18)" returns an "executable logic chunk", the ORM itself can check for things like possible null values and warn you (or hard fail).

Comment: "is not in fact "downmixed" to false — it evaluates to NULL, and because the "if" conditional is treated as a strict statement, both NULL and false fail it."  This is exactly what I mean by 'downmixing'.  You have 3 things but only 2 places to put them, resulting in information loss.  Perhaps there's a better word for that.

Comment: "This highlights exactly the point that things go off the rails: what you are expecting to be true" I'm not seeing that.  As you say null is not true or false.  Perhaps a better way of say this is that in 2VL those kinds of statements are complementary.  E.g.: if a filter a map to get keys where the value is 1 and then filter on for keys where the value is not 1, the union of those two results is the original set.  Now, I could create a new type of `null` object that behaves like SQL nulls but I don't find that desirable and it's not something I see many people choosing to do.

Comment: On a sidenote, Christophe provided [a link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/null-bas-van-gils) in his answer that I found very interesting.  In it the author asserts that in Codd's 1970 paper: ["A relational model of data for large shared data banks"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/362384.362685), there was no concept of nulls and therefore no need for 3VL.  It wasn't until 1979 that he introduced the ideas that lead to null semantics in SQL.  I'm curious about how that original idea would have worked.

Comment: @JimmyJames The distinction I was getting at is that the expression "1 > NULL" evaluates to NULL, not false. It is the fact that it is then used as an argument to a place that cannot handle 3VL (specifically something such as a 'where' clause or an if/case conditional) which causes the apparent inconsistency. In strict set-based algebra both "where the value is 1" and "where the value is not 1" are undecidable in the presence of any null candidate value, and thus the union is also undecidable (two ways, in fact).

Comment: @JimmyJames If you rephrase it as "where the value is strictly 1" and "where the value is strictly not 1", which is what such a filter does for pragmatic / usability reasons, it becomes at least slightly more obvious that the world "strictly" is covering an implication that it might be neither of those.

Comment: @JimmyJames To translate it into a "normal code" equivalent where any such comparison would trigger an exception / error… the conditional is effectively catching _and ignoring_ the equivalent to an exception, rather than propagating it. Since it has nothing to put in for any row that "blew up", it simply silently passes over them, thus making it equivalent to a row that didn't match (false). Whether this is a good answer or a bad one, at a language design choice… well, mileage clearly varies.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your point exactly but I think we are on the same page that a lot of the challenges I see relate to crossing the 'barrier' between 3VL to a binary result.  For example, a WHERE clause (to my knowledge) can be used to either include or exclude a row.  There's no 3rd option here: it's in or out.  Simiilarly, CASE could (should?) have an undecidable path that would align it better with 3VL.  I'm still not sure that would improve things though.

Comment: "the conditional is effectively catching and ignoring the equivalent to an exception" this yes, exactly.  Something that is considered terrible practice in non-SQL scenarios is a default behavior in SQL.

Comment: @JimmyJames Technically there is a third option in both of those cases. For CASE, the whole thing would evaluate to NULL, as undecidable, and a WHERE clause would just "blow up the whole query" (again, as undecidable). I can't speak to why they didn't go with that answer, I can only say that the behavior is at least consistent across the language (which is probably better than trying to mix the two, especially since a query can be a sub-query to another query).

Comment: There are inconsistencies, though.  Specifically, the source of my original error.  Why does greatest return null if there's any null parameter but min ignores nulls?  1 + null -> null but the sum of null and 1 is 1.  I know there are reasons, but I get the feeling that a lot of those reasons boil down to the problems with using 3VL in practice.

Comment: I don't expect you to know this but I'm wondering whether there's a sensible way to support outer joins in 'closed world' relational model.  I suppose the short answer is that you just need two queries but I'd be curious of other ways to handle that if nulls were not supported.

Comment: @JimmyJames I'm not entirely sure what that would even be? The whole point of an outer join is to expose cases where there is no match (i.e. one side will have a NULL). I suppose you could have a definition where a null-like-value represents "nothing found", but you then get right back into the problem of "how do you handle something that then applies a filter that depends on the value of that outer relationship?" A closed world where you cannot come up with a linkage that points to nothing is, fundamentally, what distinguishes inner joins from outer.

Comment: Right.  The simple answer is to use a 'not in' query to get those rows with no match. Effectively an outer join is union of that and an inner join.  It seems to me that this is almost a 3rd meaning of 'null'.  You can lump it in with 'inapplicable' but I think it more properly means 'a known nothing' (especially if we are in a 'closed world') and the whole 'unknown' semantics don't seem to apply to that case.

Comment: This answer was really the only one that addressed my question.  While it didn't specifically list out ways that 3VL as implemented in SQL actually solves practical problems, it was very useful in helping me get much more precise in my thinking around this.  Thanks.

Comment: *"like Yoda you speak; your verbs at the end of the clauses you put."* << This should probably be "like Yoda speak you; your verbs at the end of the clauses you put." instead: in German the verb comes at the end in auxiliary clauses, but always in second position in the main clause.

Comment: @Stef Good catch, I plead having stolen the example from elsewhere without truly speaking German (at least more than enough to say 'please' and 'thank you'). I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: This answer has aged well.  I found the other day which you might appreciate: [Incomplete Databases: Missing Records and Missing Values](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262327770_Incomplete_Databases_Missing_Records_and_Missing_Values).  Honestly, it's a little over my head but has skimming over it, I found this validating: "Since the introduction of null values in relational databases, there has been a long debate about their semantics and the correct implementation. In particular, the implementation of nulls in SQL has led to wide criticism and numerous proposals for improvement."

Answer (score 21):

> Is there any practical value to this complexity?

You can already avoid NULLs by making every storage column NOT NULL and using only INNER JOINs for processing.

The problem is that most data simply doesn't fit well into those constraints, and that's the practical value of those constraints not being compulsory.

It's a timeless complaint that SQL is too complicated, but the true situation is that there is a preponderance of naive programmers who want things to be simpler than necessary.

With `CASE A > B THEN A ELSE B`, the error is in thinking that the values of A and B fall into a range of values with a total ordering.

This is true in SQL when A and B are non-nullable (and it's unconditionally true in many other programming languages), but it isn't true when one or both are nullable.

In this respect, the `>` operator is what linguists call a *false friend*, because most people first learn its meaning in the context of another programming language where the comparison operators have certain properties and certain relationships to one another (such as that `<=` fully covers what `>` doesn't).

In SQL, the result of any comparison operator is a trilean value: TRUE, FALSE, or NULL. This is different from most languages where the result of such an operator is a boolean.

And the result of any operation involving a NULL value as an operand, is usually NULL (though there are various exceptions). This behaviour is called *null propagation*.

Written out in full and covering the cases exhaustively, `CASE A > B THEN A ELSE B` is a shorthand for:

```
CASE
    WHEN A > B THEN A
    WHEN A <= B THEN B
    WHEN A IS NULL THEN B
    WHEN B IS NULL THEN B
    END
```

That ELSE in the original one-liner is doing a hell of a lot of work.

The original programmer who introduced the bug, probably had a mental model of the exhaustive cases like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN A > B THEN A
    WHEN A <= B THEN B
    (no other cases possible)
    END
```

...and forgot to consider at all what the correct behaviour should have been when either of the operands were NULL.

Evidently the operands can be NULL, either because the storage columns can accept NULL (probably by design *and by necessity*), and/or because an OUTER JOIN was employed (again, probably by design *and by necessity*).

It's that part about there being some *necessity* of using NULLs, when the database engine is nevertheless *capable* of excluding their use, which shows that the bug which the original programmer introduced doesn't arise from a lack of facility (or extravagant complexity) in SQL, but from an error in managing the essential complexity of the problem he faced. He simply fumbled it.

**EDIT:**

Based on the following edited into the question:

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE(apple, pear) > (CASE WHEN kumquat > orange THEN kumquat ELSE orange END)
  THEN COALESCE(apple, pear)
  ELSE (CASE WHEN kumquat > orange THEN kumquat ELSE orange END
```

I would restructure this into a series of steps with exhaustive coverage of cases (boilerplate omitted for clarity):

```
apple_or_pear_or_null = CASE
    WHEN apple IS NULL AND pear IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN apple IS NOT NULL THEN apple
    WHEN pear IS NOT NULL THEN pear
    END

kumquat_or_orange_or_null = CASE 
    WHEN kumquat IS NULL AND orange IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN kumquat IS NOT NULL AND orange IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN orange IS NOT NULL AND kumquat IS NULL THEN orange
    WHEN kumquat > orange THEN kumquat
    WHEN orange <= kumquat THEN orange
    END

result = CASE
    WHEN apple_or_pear_or_null IS NULL THEN kumquat_or_orange_or_null
    WHEN kumquat_or_orange_or_null IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN apple_or_pear_or_null > kumquat_or_orange_or_null THEN apple_or_pear_or_null
    WHEN apple_or_pear_or_null <= kumquat_or_orange_or_null THEN kumquat_or_orange_or_null
    END
```

(Excuse any errors in translation here, this is off the cuff on a mobile.)

What you can see here is that the number of cases is in fact quite complicated. It's far from clear that the intention is to get "the greatest value" of all four.

If it was simply the greatest sought from all 4 possibilities, you'd do something like:

```
SELECT MAX(value) FROM (VALUES (apple), (pear), (kumquat), (orange)) AS tbl(value)
```

...which will (typically) return the greatest of the available values, or NULL if no value is available.

(Note: I'm accustomed to SQL Server, I'm attempting illustration, not to give a verbatim Oracle solution.)

**EDIT 2:**

Having reinterpreted the question once more as "why can't we dispense with NULLs entirely?", the bottom line is that relational algebra requires a special default value as part of the workings of most join operators.

The use of relational algebra (in the broadest definition of the concept) is desirable because of the algebraic properties of its operators which allows the execution engine enormous latitude for automatic, ongoing, whole-system optimisation of database workloads.

It's possible to avoid NULLs by using a special value within the domain of the base type, or with an out-of-band flag in an adjacent field, but the consequence of this ends up involving just as much complexity as NULL but with greater bespoke variety. The general-purpose NULL value is already the systematic solution to these (older) alternatives.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147511/discussion-on-answer-by-steve-does-3-valued-logic-ever-provide-practical-benefit); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 17):

This is not a bug. It's a feature. Having no information is different from having a neutral value.

NULL is not 0. NULL means there is no value known:

- If you expect for a column that NULL would be like 0, you should make this column NOT NULL and initialize its value by default to 0.
- The absence of information can be important in a number of cases. Imagine an online service where some age check is needed. If age is NULL, age is not known; it's not 0. And you may have either to require the value to be completed, or make some decision based on a business rule (e.g. if age not known, disable services requiring an age check).

In your specific case, if you want to consider NULL as zero only in a specific formula, you could use the SQL [**`COALESCE()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp) function. All mainstream RDBMS support it. But first, you need to make sure that one or two of the values being NULL is not yet another case that requires a different action:

```
CASE COALESCE(A,0) > COALESCE(B,0) THEN COALESCE(A,0) ELSE COALESCE(B,0)
```

More on NULL value and its [semantics and tips and tricks here](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/sql-null-values/).

## EDIT

In the meanwhile your question was enriched multiple times, including with the COALESCE proposal (giving the wrong impression that my answer paraphrases the question, which was not the case when I wrote it). So let me add some considerations:

- Codd introduced NULL in relational algebra to represent either an unknown value or the fact that a value is not applicable (see [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/null-bas-van-gils?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_ios&utm_campaign=share_via) for precise references)
- Later, Codd even proposed a four value logic, for distinguishing between NULL+applicable and NULL+not/applicable (see resaearch paper [*NULL in databases revisited*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/382272.382416). This distinction was not taken over in SQL - but is implemented in Excel ;-)
- A *binary* comparison operator requires *two* operands. In 3vL, if one is missing, the operation   is evaluated to NULL (in the sense not applicable), because there is only one operand (or less) and it the ioeration is not defined with one operand or less (and since the condition is not true, else is fired). All this is perfectly consistent with Codd's initial definition of NULL.
- Moreover, without NULL, there would be no outer join possible. In the outer join, the relevant columns for corresponding missing rows are NULL to ean that having a value is not applicable. And if you would any comparison with such columns would not be applicable either.

Comment: Small point: there are often slightly confused statements about whether NULL is a value of a special kind, or a "missing" value (i.e. a non-value). My preferred view is that NULL is a value that is treated specially by operators, and the *rationale* for that special treatment is because the NULL value is intended generally to *represent* missing or inapplicable information in a systematic way.

Comment: @Steve the subtle difference between a value of a special kind,  or the  absence of value is worth its own question. I have not read the most recent versions of the SQL standard for the authoritative definition, but according to [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#:~:text=In%20SQL%2C%20null%20or%20NULL,not%20exist%20in%20the%20database.) it's a marker to indicate that no value exist, which seems to combine the two point of views.  ut whatever the definition there is indeed a real reason why it makes sense to have it.

Comment: More subtlety: in some domains it may happen that "no value, not applicable, none" and "we don't know" are different. But NULL doesn't help to distinguish that. Only "no value in the row/col", without further details.

Comment: *"seems to combine the two point of views"* - that's exactly the problem. In my view, NULL is a value because it is a defined state that can be processed into other defined states. It may be a defined state that represents that something is missing, but the *record* that something is missing isn't missing, it is present - (it's a "known unknown", in Rumsfeldian terms). I'm unclear what advantages exist for the other way of thinking - but I suspect I employ a level of indirection between what the records *say*, and what they *mean* or *represent*, whereas the other way conflates the two.

Comment: I agree that avoiding null values is the best pragmatic solution but it's out of my hands and I've worked with SQL for more than two decades so I know how to handle nulls.  The question is more about relational theory and why the choice to treat nulls in this way was made and/or is there some inherent benefit to it working this way.

Comment: @JimmyJames In the order of ease of change: 1) the expression; 2) the schema; 3) the sql standard ;-)  For the use cases, I gave an example. For the origin, according to the wikipedia article I quoted for Steve, it dates back to Codd himself, so the founder of relational algebra. No wonder that SQL standard took it over.

Comment: @Christophe Yeah, I'm not trying to change SQL.  I have enough Sisyphean goals.  I'm just wondering if I'm missing something.  Am I trying to row upstream in my battles with nulls?  Is there a different way to think about it that would streamline our SQL and make it easier to reason about?

Comment: From a more modern perspective, about properties, independently of SQL and from a theoretical perspective, UML has a semantic model where properties can be  attibutes or association ends, and both are almost equivalent. Both can have multiplicities with a lower bound of 0:  an attribute having  no value  is  equivalent to no association/link with a value object. The NULL correspond to the case where the cardinality (in UML speak, i.e. an instance of a multiplicity) is 0.  UML was defined independently from SQL but interestingly the two semantics are consistent in this regard.

Comment: @Christophe I read something a while back about how an alternate language was being supported for BigQuery (I think).  I remember the reasoning being that it was more composable but I can't find anything now and I don't know how it handled nulls.

Comment: I think age check is a great example: One wants an explicit "WHEN age IS NULL" check to trigger special behavior, like asking the user to verify their age. Which is different from any value the age might have. - But I also think SQL could have benefited from a second non-value like UNDEFINED in JavaScript, which behaves the same, but is distinct. But that would need even more discipline for data administration, to make sure the right value is used (and reality shows, NULL is already too complex for most users)

Comment: To be clear, the 'coalesce' was not due to any proposal you made.  It was in the original code and my solution which was doen before asking.  And that's why this answer isn't really addressing my question.  You are explaining 3-VL and that Codd did it.  But I already know all of that.  I'm asking for a specific concrete example of when this is actually useful in a practical way.  I can only think of times when this causes extra work and problems.  When it is a good thing?

Comment: @JimmyJames My point is that I introduced Coalesce in my answer on 21 July at 6:37.  You may have found this solution before, and nobody claims you didn't know about it. Nobody challenges your skills.  But you introduced it in your question only on 21 July at 15:39 making my answer suddenly looking like a plagiarism. Moreover you keep editing your question depending on the answers provided. This is not the way SE should work. It's not a site for dialogue but for Q&A. Isn't it    disrespectfull for all contributors who answered and who constantly need to monitor it to be sure to stay relevant?

Comment: @Christophe If you are worried that someone would think you are answering in bad faith or something like that, I think those fears are unwarranted and I can personally vouch for you as a trusted member of the community.

Comment: @Christophe "Moreover you keep editing your question depending on the answers provided. .... Isn't it disrespectfull for all contributors who answered and who constantly need to monitor it to be sure to stay relevant?" I definitely agree that this isn't optimal.  The main reason I have done that is that I've gotten feedback that explicitly that 'my question title is misleading' and a bunch of answers that don't address the question.  I find that very frustrating but I'm doing my best to not take it personally and work to clarify.  I apologize if you feel tricked or mislead.

Comment: "This distinction was not taken over in SQL - but is implemented in Excel ;-)" Yes.  Let's be thankful for that: https://www.marketwatch.com/story/88-of-spreadsheets-have-errors-2013-04-17

Comment: +1 for the Bas van Gils article.  It is very aligned with my thinking.

Comment: I wanted to give you an additional bounty of 50 points here but it seems I can only create a bigger bounty (at least double.)  I might still do it, but I wanted you to know that this was very helpful and that I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @JimmyJames No problem. Thanks for this positive feedback. Very much appreciated. And thanks for the challenging and interesting exchange :-)

Comment: @JimmyJames Wow, I just received a lot of points ! I didn't even know that it was possible to attribute a bounty to more than one person ! Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Does 3-valued logic ever provide practical benefits over 2-valued logic?

I can give you a concrete example where using 3VL was very useful (Whether it's a *good* example is up for debate.)

A program I worked on had a requirement to pass along certain data sets to an older legacy system. This system wasn't really designed for this kind of operation so sending superfluous data would get its knickers in a twist just as badly as sending the incorrect data. The peculiarities of which dataset to send when turned out to be a huge source of bugs, endless streams of if statements and vast amounts of duplication. It was also impossible to make changes to without doing a full release of the code base (This was in a bank in the "good old days" so a release cycle could be months long)

Someone cleverer than I decided to use a truth table / matrix of columns to represent the 20-ish decisions required to determine if a dataset should be required. It looked kind of like this:

| ProductId | IsABusiness | decision-2 | ...decision-N | Dataset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ds1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ds2 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | ds3 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ds2 |

and so on.

Pretty standard so far, but still a little cumbersome for this use case, because some datasets would apply for any ProductId (as an example) or not care about whether the application was for a business.

This is where NULL comes in. **A NULL in a column meant that we did not care about that column in our decision-making process**: a NULL in the productId column meant the dataset applied to all products, a NULL in the IsABusiness column meant that the rule applied regardless of whether the applicant was a business or not.

We could express some fairly interesting decision using this style (e.g., a Business applying for a specific type of loan which already has a loan with the bank and is older than 3 years), without having to expressly write out *NumDecisions^2^NumProducts* rows. If a new requirement came in, adding a column didn't break existing rules.

Does this count as a practical benefit of 3VL over 2VL? I think so.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I really appreciate the straight answer.  Can you elaborate or clarify how three-valued-logic tied into the solution. Maybe I need more coffee but I'm not seeing where rules like `1 > null -> null` fit into this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fight this guy : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql

Sure you could throw an error when you hit a NULL or a NaN and some operations do.

The benefit of not doing so is that when you are running your operation on sets of data rather than a single operation, having a single row cause the whole set to fail is not seen as a good thing.

Given the preponderance of null values in databases if you chose to throw an error when you hit a null in a calculation everyone's sql would be littered with these kind of "how do i solve the divide by zero problem" IFNULLs

You would *still* get silent failures because you would have wrapped your greater than calculation in the various coalesce functions to make it work. Plus your SQL would look ugly

Comment: I don't see any reason to fight anyone on that answer.   It's an SO question about how to solve a programming problem.  I am not asking a programming problem.  I am asking about (roughly) language design.  Imagine you were migrating a system and you have a choice: a 'NoSQL' with a boolean query syntax database and an SQL DB that uses trinary syntax.  All else equal (and it never is, but humor me) what are the practical 'pros' of [three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) for a team whose members tend to have low to moderate programming skills?

Comment: Sort of an aside but something I realized in this (painful) attempt to get an straight answer is that it wouldn't be too hard for an SQL query to provide static guidance on this.  That is, if a column allows null, the engine could refuse to compile your statement if you haven't declared what you want to do with null values.  Along the same lines, it seems to me that the `CASE` statement should have a 'NULL' clause along with ELSE.  If you choose 3-valued logic, I think you should commit to it.  No pun intended.

Comment: my point is that SQL does have your two valued logic for division. Where it does so people complain that it isn't three valued logic and add functions to make it three valued.

Comment: I don't think you are interpreting that correctly.  When people have errors in their solutions that prevent them from running, they tend to find solutions.  That's actually kind of core to my question.  I would much rather get an error that tells me I messed up than some coin-flip result which could go undetected for a decade (as is the case with the example I give in the question.)

Comment: well exactly, but I think you are missing the point here, you would have hit the null problem on day one and added one of your coalesce solutions, only to find ten years later you had picked the wrong one for some scenario. Just like this guy and his divide by zero solution which still doesn't work when the divisor is null

Comment: Have you seen all the discussion?  I don't have time to talk about pointless hypotheticals.  If you have a concrete example: show and prove.

Comment: divide by zero is the concrete example. Its two valued and people make it three valued so their SQL works. QED

Comment: It's a concrete example of good design, I agree.

Comment: Now convince everyone than NaN semantics are good.

Comment: you would have to argue the pros and cons with all the people who upvoted that and all the other "how do i solve divide by zero in SQL" questions. But surely you can see that without three valued logic you are forced to write longer SQL which essentially produces the same result?

Comment: I think javascript nailed NaNs

Comment: LOL.  I tried.  I really tried: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: to take you literally, that question is an example of where three valued logic would have saved that person a problem

Comment: Not really.  It's an example of a how it would save a person from a minor development task by risking incorrect behavior.

Comment: This persons code was broken, they posted their "problem" on stackoverflow and got a "solution" which they then (presumably) implemented "solving" their "problem". Are you really saying that they are an outlier and normal people don't get this "problem"?

Comment: also, "I don't see any reason to fight anyone on that answer. It's an SO question about how to solve a programming **problem**..."

Comment: Set SQL aside for a moment.  Do you think it's a good idea to squash exceptions?

Comment: No, I think you have a point, most languages would be throwing null exceptions. You totally could take the same approach they have with div by zero with nulls and it would force you to explicitly spell out what you are doing with nulls

Comment: I would then make a fortune selling SQL 2.0, all operators account for null values

Comment: SQL 3.0 NaN is a thing! you can chain numerical operations and not have to worry about infinity!

Comment: SQL 4.0 just put everything in unstructured big json blobs!!! Its scalable!

Comment: I actually don't think there's any chance of fully getting away from SQL, at least at my organization.  I am trying to convince people to avoid building highly complex queries (the example in the question is one small part of a query with 16 joins) and do 'everything' in SQL, though.  Recently there's been some discussion about doubling-down on SQL and I'm trying to get my finger on exactly what my argument against that is.  Seems we are closer than we thought.

Comment: its not just sql you can get the same three valued logic with nullable types, I think I read somewhere that the most common bug is not accounting for nulls. Put units tests on everything

Comment: I think I'd banish nulls in general if I had my druthers.  I'm not sure I'm smart enough to come up with an alternative so don't ask.  They are bad enough.  But 3VL adds a whole layer of complexity to the problem that I am more and more convinced isn't valuable.

Comment: I think rust doesn't have null, but functional languages have extra nulls. You have to recognise  that SQL has a lot of nulls and it makes sense for the operators to have some sort of default handling of them

Comment: Rust is something I need to resume learning.  Maybe won't 'win' but it's going to influence future languages for sure.  I get it, SQL is what it it is.  I just want to make sure I'm not missing something when I come with a hard 'no' on expanding our use of it.  BTW: Edit your question somehow.

Comment: In passing: getting people to avoid building highly complex queries is almost always the right answer. Most of the "true power" of SQL is primarily useful for _reporting_ purposes where the query is innately complex to express a complex question… but rarely is that very useful from a programmer's point of view _unless_ they are writing reporting functionality. And reporting is easier to write when other queries aren't doing strange deep magic to accomplish their work.

Comment: @JoelAelwyn I agree with that.  Part of the problem here is that the databases we are working with are often poorly designed and implemented.  Answering simple questions can require may joins and nested queries if you do it in SQL.  For example, I stumbled upon this bug in the SQL when converting it to a much more straightforward dump of rows and doing the rest in Python (as an experiment.)  The logic is much clearer and shorter (the case statement becomes a filter and max call) but it means pulling many more (e.g. hundreds instead of dozens) of rows.   It's not the easiest idea to sell.

Answer (score 1):

I have been involved with databases for nearly 20 years of my now retired career.

The need for null aware logic has surfaced many times, often when we did not expect it. Say you have a table of users that can apply for various low-income benefits. Suddenly the business requirement for a new benefit is invented that requires the applicant to be over 18 years of age. So we start collecting date of birth, but existing users don't have this data. Using nulls means that standard reporting functions like average age of birth return correct data - they work against records that have the data and ignore nulls

So given this background embrace null logic, and carefully evaluate case logic in particular.

Comment: Are you claiming that you can't solve such problems with 2-valued logic?  I'm certain that you can.

Comment: @JimmyJames Of course you can roll your own. But SQL has solved the problem so why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: No idea what you talking about.  I never mentioned 'rolling my own'.  I don't think you understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Does 3-valued logic ever provide practical benefits over 2-valued logic?

**Yes.** It's frequently the case in programming that values don't exist, and that using some valid value as a default is awkward or unacceptable. In short, it's often very useful to be able to distinguish between *false* and *unknown*.

Consider, for example, a database that tracks donations to a political campaign. You might design a table so that it has a `has-donated` column with a nullable boolean value: you either know that a potential donor has donated to the campaign, or you know that they haven't donated, or you don't yet know whether they have or haven't. In order to express the same thing with two-valued logic, you'd need multiple columns for `has-donated` and `has-not-donated`, because `has-donated` being false might mean that the potential donor has definitely not donated, or it might mean that you don't know. And if you did have those two columns, you'd have to write a bunch of code to manage them carefully, so that you never ended up in a weird situation where both `has-donated` and `has-not-donated` are true.

SQL has a `NOT NULL` modifier that prevents rows from being added unless they contain values for any columns marked `NOT NULL`. This simplifies code because you know that you don't have to consider NULL values in columns so marked, and that's a big benefit in itself.

The motivation SQL's three-valued logic is similar to that behind optional types in languages like Swift, Kotlin, Rust, etc. Optional types let the programmer explicitly state her intentions about whether a variable is allowed to have "no value", and they let the compiler ensure that code that uses optional variables checks for a valid value before using it. They eliminate an entire class of programming errors where programmers forget to check for sentinel values like `nil`.

If SQL's three-valued logic seems onerous, it might be that you haven't considered the benefits of using `NOT NULL` in cases where that makes sense.

Comment: A fair attempt at addressing the question but I'm not asking what null means or whether nulls are OK (it's a valid question, just not what I am asking here.)  I'm asking what 3VL around nulls provides.  You can have 2VL with nulls.  For example, if the condition null <> 1 resulted in true, instead of null, that would be one valid way to implement 2VL while allowing nulls.

Comment: @JimmyJames There are a number of different 3-valued logics (e.g. HT, Lukasiewicz, Kleene, etc). If the logic considers 3 values such as *true*, *false*, and *null*, then it's some sort of 3VL, not 2VL. And again, the value of SQL's particular 3VL is that it lets you handle nulls in a graceful way (instead of, say, throwing an error) while still not assuming that the value is something other than null.

Comment: You can safely assume that I understand what nulls and 3VL are.  'Gracefully' is an interesting word.  I don't consider incorrect results to be 'graceful' (quite the opposite) and my assertion (prove me wrong here if you can) is that in practical use, 3VL (as implemented SQL) tends to increase the chance of incorrect results when it comes into play.  The primary reason is that most developers are unfamiliar, if not completely ignorant of it.  The question is: if that's correct, is there some benefit to the additional complexity of 3VL here that makes up for all the problems it creates.

Comment: @JimmyJames *All* the current answers here correctly explain the issue from different perspectives. I added mine mainly because I think that the comparison to optionals in other languages is compelling and, if you're familiar with optionals, explanatory. It's clear from the question that you would prefer different behavior (*I would just prefer more standard boolean semantics*), and I think that your wish for something else is making it hard for you to see any benefit to the current behavior. As such, I'm not sure that any good-faith answer will satisfy you.

Comment: I really am not emotionally attached to this.  You wrote that I won't "see any benefit to the current behavior".  Has any answer pointed to some?  Do you think it's fair to refuse to point out the benefits because you believe I won't accept them?  What are they?  Is it a secret?  Please stop assuming you know what I think, want, or wish for.  Read my question *literally* and answer it *literally*.  I've got a bunch of answers explaining how nulls and 3VL work in SQL.  I already know that.  If that's what I was asking, I would ask "how do nulls and 3VL work in SQL?"  Why is this so hard?

Comment: @JimmyJames, do you have some sort of chip on your shoulder about the idea that people can make *inferences* - not assumptions - about your agenda and strength of feeling on a topic? Quite apart from the fact that you've explicitly admitted - somewhere amongst the thickets now - that your agenda at work is to reduce the use of SQL. This answer lists a "benefit" of 3VL - which you claim to be seeking - in the paragraph beginning "Consider, for example...". And for clarity, Caleb has already commented that he does not think the use of null is distinct from using 3VL (which I also agree with).

Comment: @Steve I consider this a professional forum where people can discuss technical issues dispassionately.  I am not interested in discussing my feelings or yours here.

Comment: @JimmyJames, nobody's discussing your feelings, we're perceiving your apparent agenda and tailoring our remarks so as to be pertinent to that. That doesn't mean the answers are at cross purposes, or that information has been withheld. There's been considerable engagement, and there's been no limitation on you asking for more. But you don't seem to integrate anything that is actually said. You say you understand all about 3VL. But you don't seem to get that 3VL is so called because null forms the *third logical value*. You posit a "2VL with null", without distinguishing this from 3VL. (1/2)

Comment: It's like asking what is the benefit of the Holy Trinity - can't we just manage with the Father, Son, and Holy Ghost? To any sensible person, the Holy Trinity *is those three things*. Likewise, 3VL is the values of true, false, null. 2VL + null = 3VL. That is the conventional understanding of these terms. You can ask us to interpret an unconventional definition, but you need to be explicit about what that definition is *as part of your question*. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve Look either provide a list of specific concrete benefits or stop pestering me.  I don't have any interest in whatever this is.

Comment: @JimmyJames, if you don't have any interest in listening to answers, then go away and stop pestering those who have already answered you. In fact hectoring people with snide remarks like "why is this so hard?".

Comment: @Steve do you just need to get the last word in?  Go for it.  I won't respond.  Stop adding comments.   Leave me alone.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the `COALESCE`-issue in your edits: The problem here is not really due to three-valued logic specifically. The problem is you have a set of columns that you want to filter and sort. Unfortunately, SQL only supports filtering and sorting on sets of rows, not on sets of columns. If the data was rows in a single column, it would be trivial to exclude NULL's and then take the MAX, if you want the highest non-null value.

---

3-valued logic is necessary to be able to query datasets that contain *unknown* values, i.e. `NULL`'s. Without 3-valued logic, such a query would either fail or give incorrect results in some cases. Neither is desirable.

`NULL` in SQL mean *unknown* or *not applicable*. (This should not be confused with the semantics of `null`'s in programming languages like Java or JavaScript (or `None` in Python) where it means *no object* or just *nothing*. *Nothing* is very different from *unknown*! For example, a person having no address is very different from a person having an unknown address.)

You are specifically questioning the semantics of `greatest`. If any value in the list provided is NULL, the result is NULL. This is derived from the behavior of binary comparisons - if one of the operands is unknown, the result is unknown.

This might be annoying in this particular case where you just want the largest non-null value. But the general principle of three-valued logic is extremely important because it prevent the database from giving misleading answers to queries.

Lets say you have a database of customers. Some of them have registered their age, but not all (i.e. age is NULL). Now for some legal reason you need to check if there are any customers below the age of 21, so you ask for the age of the youngest customer. If this query just ignored NULL's it could give you a dangerously wrong answer. E.g. you might begin selling alchold to customers below the age of 21, which might land you in jail.

More generally the principle is that a query should not lie if it doesn't know the answer. If the query is x < 21 and x is unknown at the time, you want the query to tell you the answer is unknown. Answering either true or false would potentially be incorrect and could lead to serious trouble.

The query engine could signal an error and abort the query in case of an operation involving nulls. But this would also prevent the database from giving a *correct* and useful output in many cases. Sometimes, knowing that an answer is unknown is quite useful information!

For example, you might want a list of all customers below the age of 21 - acknowledging that you don't know the age of all customers. But you can't use `age < 21` since if age is `NULL` for some customers, the whole query will be rejected. Couldn't you just filter the `NULL`-valued away in a `WHERE`-condition? No, because a relational query engine is allowed to re-arrange the order of operations, so you can't guarantee the nulls are filtered away before the comparison.

Even worse, you might have a query that works correctly because the current data doesn't happen to have any null values even though the column is defined as nullable. Adding a valid record that contains a `NULL` value could then cause cascading failures in the system.

The only safe approach would then be to *always* add a case-expression guarding against `NULL`, eg.

```
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN age IS NULL 
            THEN NULL
            ELSE age >= 21
    END AS is_of_drinking_age;
```

This will work, but it is a lot of boilerplate which just introduces your own 3-value logic in an ad-hoc manner. It might be more explicit but it is certainly not more practical.

All of this trouble is of course because we allow NULL values in data. But even if we disallow NULL's in base tables, they may still appear in left/right/outer joins, so they are not easily eliminated.

Comment: But it's not as if there's no solution for this in 2-valued logic.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'necessary' here.

Comment: "If SQL didn't have three-valued logic it would be forced to return either true or false".  It could raise an error like many (most?) SQL engines do for division by zero.

Comment: @JimmyJames: Yes it could raise an error on operations involving a null value. But that would in many cases prevent queries from giving a *correct* result even when it would be possible to give a correct result. This would make the query engine overall less useful. I have amended the answer a bit to detail the problems.

Comment: "many cases prevent queries from giving a correct result even when it would be possible to give a correct result" By not erroring on such comparisons, it allows queries to produce incorrect results without warning.  That is far more common in my experience than the 'it worked even though I wrote the wrong code' scenario.  When something raises an error, you will find out.  When something fails silently, those issues can go unnoticed and really bad things can happen in the real world.

Comment: Let me try to come at it from a different direction.  Are you saying that this is the benefit is convenience?  That the reason this useful is because people writing SQL are not forced to consider how missing/non-applicable results should be treated?  A kind of 'get what you get' situation?

Comment: @JimmyJames: I don't agree that queries "produce incorrect results without warning". Of course if you *expect* 2-valued logic, 3-valued logic might be surprising, but there is nothing *incorrect* about it. Arguably the presence of nulls in the queried data might indicate an error (I certainly prefer to avoid nullable data as much as possible), but then the nulls should be eliminated at the schema level. But *if* nulls exist in the queried data, 3-valued logic is IMHO the only correct way to handle it.

Comment: " But if nulls exist in the queried data, 3-valued logic is IMHO the only correct way to handle it."  The only way?  Surely that's hyperbole.  Are you suggesting that if someone processes (e.g.) JSON document with nulls in it, it's incorrect to do so in language with 2VL semantics such as Javascript or Python?

Comment: @JimmyJames: Nulls mean something entirely different in JavaScript, so it can't really be compared to NULL's in SQL, despite the similar name. In JavaScript (and most other general-purpose programming languages), nulls are a distinct value, different from any other value, while in SQL nulls represent an *unknown* value which *might* be the same as any other value - we don't know. 3-valued logic follows from this specific semantics of NULL's in SQL. (Of course JSON itself does not have any intrinsic semantics, and nulls can be used to represent whatever the users agree on.)

Comment: "Nulls mean something entirely different in JavaScript, so it can't really be compared to NULL's in SQL" But that's the whole point of the question.  You've come right around to the beginning.  Essentially you are saying nulls in SQL are not like nulls in other languages because of 3VL.  But you need to imagine what SQL would look like if it allowed nulls and didn't support 3VL to answer the question.

Comment: @JimmyJames: No I'm saying something slightly different: That the semantics of NULL's in SQL databases is they represent an unknown value. 3-valued logic *follows* from this (rather than the other way around), but it also have other consequences, for example that NULL + 17 yields NULL, because adding 17 to an unknown value is still an unknown value. So perhaps your question is why SQL need the concept of an unknown value?

Comment: Yes.  That is the underlying context of the question.  I really don't know what more I can do to get people to realize I understand 3VL and how it works in SQL.

Comment: Imagine I created a new query language called 'simplified SQL' when transpiled into standard SQL (pretend there's real standard.)  This new language would eliminate the 3VL logic in SQL.  In other words, treat NULLs as a 'distinct value' instead of 'unknown'.  What would we lose by using such a language?

Comment: @JimmyJames: You would lose the ability to work with unknown values. You cant use nulls to represent unknown values since that would mean all unknown values were the same value.

Comment: What specifically would I lose?  Are you saying that there's no way to deal with unknown values in 2VL languages?

Comment: As an example I was able to replace the `CASE` statement with a client side solution in Python: `max(filter(None, apple, pear, kumquat, orange))` This is much simpler, reasonably easy to understand, and has the side-benefit of being exactly correct.

Comment: @JimmyJames: I dont know of any language with 2VL which support the concept of unknown values. Do you know of any examples?

Comment: If you mean unknown in terms of the 3VL semantics of SQL, it's absolutely true that there are no 2VL languages with 3VL semantics.  If you are asking if there are 2VL languages that support a value that means 'unknown' or 'not applicable', Python has `None`, JS has `null`, Java has `null`. Do you need me to name some others?

Comment: I should note that you could create a type with the 3VL semantics similar to SQL in Python (for example) but it would likely result in a lot of bugs largely same reason that it does in SQL.

Comment: @JimmyJames: null in Java/JS and None in Python do not have the semantics of *unknown*, they have the semantics of *nothing* or *missing*, which is significantly different. Think of the difference between a person having no address and having an unknown address. If you think NULL in SQL has the semantics of null in those programming languages, then you will get bugs - but you will also get bugs in Java if you think Java null has the semantics of SQL NULL.

Comment: The whole point of the question is what would be less effective if nulls in SQL didn't have unknown semantics.  It's really pointless to keep reiterating the basic context of that.  I know they have unknown semantics.  What if they didn't?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147519/discussion-between-jacquesb-and-jimmyjames).

Answer (score 0):

### Key Point

Think of SQL as a way of processing lots of data in parallel, and NULL means that this value is unknown.  Greatest(....) should return NULL if one or more data values are NULL because one of the unknown values might be the greatest, or they might not be...  We do not know.

### Detail

This is an interesting question because the correct answer flies in the face of conventional programming wisdom.

In creating application code, the perceived wisdom is that you should write your function to always succeed with the result. If an error occurs, it should be raised as an exception. The purpose of this is to simplify your codebase. The alternative is checking every function return value to verify the call succeeded. Very soon, the amount of error handling overwhelms your code base.

In SQL, at a simplistic level, it can be "just data storage and retrieval". However, as products and services grow, things never remain simple long enough.

As application requirements change, additional values are needed for data entities. For some data, inserting a default value where the actual value is unknown may be possible. In the world of Data protection, subject access requests and laws requiring data records to be accurate, it is not acceptable to insert a valid value into the actual data leaving no way to know if that was the default or an actual data value. This is why NULL is essential as a valid data value.

As a programmer, I'd love it if all business logic occurred in the code layers and SQL databases were restricted to CRUD operations. Performance-wise, it is many times more performant to move the code to the data than to ship the data to the code. In other words, application and business logic inevitably occur within the SQL Database server environment.

In the NoSQL world, there is everyday awareness of the pattern **Map**, **Transform**, **Reduce**, where each phase happens separately and allows the map and transform stages to be highly distributed, with only the reduce step tending to happen sequentially.

With SQL, **Select**, **Join**, and **Where** statements are part of the map phase. Computing additional row values from existing data is part of the transform phase, and functions such as **Group By** and **Count** are part of the reduce phase. And this is where the simplicity ends.

The value of SQL is its ability to run complex business and application logic efficiently by executing the code close to the data source. This brings with it the challenge of handling situations where logic cannot provide the answer, and this is the problem that **NULL** solves.

*How to handle errors when execution of the program occurs over multiple sets of data in parallel.*

Your SQL application may be processing 20,000 data records through the business logic.  Rather than failing the whole process, isn't it better to provide as much of the output as possible and use NULL to identify where the data could not be obtained?

Thinking about the use of logic and SQL functions this way means that having functions passed NULL as one of their data values probably should return NULL as their result.